# Property 'mapReduce' does not exist on type 'Collection<any>'

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, angular, meteor, typescript

Good day, I have defined a mongo collection in this way:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection<elementsType>("my_collection_name");
```

after I try to execute a mapReduce() call over it, by doing:

```
function mapReducing(): void {

    let mapFunction = function () {
        let idd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        this.emit(idd, 10);
    };

    let reduceFunction = function (taskId, values) {
        return values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    };

    Tasks.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {out: "my_ouput_collection_name"});
}
```

BUT server throws this error when is launched:

```
Property 'mapReduce' does not exist on type 'Collection<any>'.
```

and then when I call mapReducing() function, it displays error above:

```
Exception from sub testing id X69HTPSZmBqw8RMRd TypeError: index_1.Tasks.mapReduce is not a function
```

any Ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: covert function to use `Arrow Function`

Comment: ty, but arrow functions would not fix the issue.

Comment: What's the relationship between Tasks and TaskItems?

Comment: sorry is the same, I just edited it.

Comment: I don't think Meteor's `Mongo.Collection` has map reduce. You can access the original mongo collection as `Tasks._collection.rawCollection()` and use map reduce on that. You'll of course lose the reactivity that Meteor's collection offer.